# java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points, Crash APP

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

I am having this error for and I have been struggling to get it fixed. My app keeps crashing anytime i search for Location. As soon as I click on "GO" to get me a define Location, the app crashes. I have searched all over SO for solution, but nothing seems to be forth coming.

This is my LogCat

```
    --------- beginning of crash
09-23 19:39:05.275 6736-6736/com.example.mac.uberclone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mac.uberclone, PID: 6736
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.mac.uberclone.Welcome$4.onResponse(Welcome.java:256)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

My App Gradle is below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mac.uberclone"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//Add Library
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:latest.integration'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My Welcome activity

```
package com.example.mac.uberclone;

import android.Manifest;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mac.uberclone.Common.Common;
import com.example.mac.uberclone.Remote.IGoogleAPI;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import   com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.JointType;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.SquareCap;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class Welcome extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener
{

private GoogleMap mMap;

//Play Service
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 7000;
private static final int PLAY_SERVICE_RES_REQUEST = 7001;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;

private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;

DatabaseReference drivers;
GeoFire geoFire;

Marker mCurrent;

MaterialAnimatedSwitch location_switch;
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

//Car Animation
private List<LatLng> polyLineList;
private Marker carMarker;
private float v;
private double lat,lng;
private Handler handler;
private LatLng startPosition,endPosition,currentPosition;
private int index,next;
private Button btnGo;
private EditText editPlace;
private String destination;
private PolylineOptions polylineOptions,blackPolylineOptions;
private Polyline blackPolyline,greyPolyline;

private IGoogleAPI mService;


Runnable drawPathRunnable =new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (index<polyLineList.size()-1);
        {
            index++;
            next = index +1;
        }
        if (index < polyLineList.size()-1)
        {
            startPosition = polyLineList.get(index);
            endPosition = polyLineList.get(next);
        }

        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0,1);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(3000);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                v = valueAnimator.getAnimatedFraction();
                lng = v*endPosition.longitude+(1-v)*startPosition.longitude;
                lat = v*endPosition.latitude+(1-v)*startPosition.latitude;
                LatLng newPos = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                carMarker.setPosition(newPos);
                carMarker.setAnchor(0.5f,0.5f);
                carMarker.setRotation(getBearing(startPosition,newPos));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                        new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(newPos)
                        .zoom(15.5f)
                        .build()
                ));
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.start();
        handler.postDelayed(this,3000);
    }
};

private float getBearing(LatLng startPosition, LatLng endPosition) {
    double lat = Math.abs(startPosition.latitude - endPosition.latitude);
    double lng = Math.abs(startPosition.longitude - endPosition.longitude);

    if (startPosition.latitude < endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude < endPosition.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat)));
    else if (startPosition.latitude >= endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude < endPosition.longitude)
        return (float) ((90-Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat)))+90);
    else if (startPosition.latitude >= endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude >= endPosition.longitude)
        return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat))+180);
    else if (startPosition.latitude < endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude >= endPosition.longitude)
        return (float) ((90-Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng/lat)))+270);
        return -1;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    handler = new Handler();
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //Init View
    location_switch = (MaterialAnimatedSwitch)findViewById(R.id.location_switch);
    location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(boolean isOnline) {
            if (isOnline)
            {
                startLocationUpdates();
                displayLocation();
                Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are online",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            else
            {
                stopLocationUpdates();
                mCurrent.remove();
                mMap.clear();
                handler.removeCallbacks(drawPathRunnable);
                Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You are offline",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        }
    });

    polyLineList = new ArrayList<>();
    btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
    editPlace = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPlace);

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            destination = editPlace.getText().toString();
            destination = destination.replace("", "+");//Replace Space with + to fetch data
            Log.d("EDMTDEV",destination);

            getDirection();
        }
    });

    //Geo Fire
    drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers");
    geoFire = new GeoFire (drivers);

    setUpLocation();

    mService = Common.getGoogleAPI();
}

private void getDirection() {
    currentPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude());

    String requestApi = null;
    try{

        requestApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"+
                "mode=driving&"+
                "transit_routing_preference=less_driving&"+
                "origin="+currentPosition.latitude+","+currentPosition.longitude+"&"+
                "destination="+destination+"&"+
                "Key="+ getResources().getString(R.string.google_direction_api);
        Log.d("EDMTDEV",requestApi);// Print URL for debug
        mService.getPath(requestApi)
                .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject route = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONObject poly = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                                String polyline = poly.getString("Points");
                                polyLineList = decodePoly(polyline);

                            }


                            if (!polyLineList.isEmpty()) {
                                //Adjusting bounds
                                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                                for (LatLng latLng : polyLineList)
                                    builder.include(latLng);
                                LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                                CameraUpdate mCameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 2);
                                mMap.animateCamera(mCameraUpdate);
                            }

                            polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                            polylineOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
                            polylineOptions.width(5);
                            polylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                            polylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                            polylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                            polylineOptions.addAll(polyLineList);
                            greyPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                            blackPolylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                            blackPolylineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
                            blackPolylineOptions.width(5);
                            blackPolylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                            blackPolylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                            blackPolylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                            blackPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(blackPolylineOptions);

                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(polyLineList.get(polyLineList.size()-1))
                                    .title("Pickup Location"));

                            //Animation
                            ValueAnimator polyLineAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,100);
                            polyLineAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                            polyLineAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                            polyLineAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                                    List<LatLng> points = greyPolyline.getPoints();
                                    int percentValue = (int)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                                    int size = points.size();
                                    int newPoints = (int) (size * (percentValue/100.0f));
                                    List<LatLng> p = points.subList(0,newPoints);
                                    blackPolyline.setPoints(p);
                                }
                            });
                            polyLineAnimator.start();

                            carMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition)
                            .flat(true)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car)));

                            handler = new Handler();
                            index=-1;
                            next=1;
                            handler.postDelayed(drawPathRunnable,3000);



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, ""+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private List decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List poly = new ArrayList();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}


//Press Ctrl+O


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

            {
                if (checkPlayServices())
                {
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    createLocationRequest();
                    if (location_switch.isChecked())
                        displayLocation();
                }
            }

    }
}

private void setUpLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        //Request runtime permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    else
    {
       if (checkPlayServices())
       {
           buildGoogleApiClient();
           createLocationRequest();
           if (location_switch.isChecked())
               displayLocation();
       }
    }

}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mlocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mlocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mlocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mlocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    this.mLocationRequest = mlocationRequest;


}

private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode))
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,this,PLAY_SERVICE_RES_REQUEST).show();
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}


private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);
}

private void displayLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null)
    {
        if (location_switch.isChecked())
        {
            final double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            final double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            //Update to firebase
            geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                    //Add marker
                    if (mCurrent != null)
                        mCurrent.remove(); //Remove already marker
                    mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                .position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude))
                                                .title("Your Location"));

                    // Move camera to this position
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,longitude),15.0f));
                }
            });
        }
        else
            {
                Log.d("Error", "Cannot get your location");
            }
    }

}

private void rotateMarker(final Marker mCurrent, final float i, GoogleMap mMap) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final float startRotation = mCurrent.getRotation();
    final long duration = 1500;


    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float)elapsed/duration);
            float rot = t*i+(1-t)*startRotation;
            mCurrent.setRotation(-rot > 180?rot/2:rot);
            if (t<1.0)
            {
                handler.postDelayed(this,16);
            }
        }
    });

}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    displayLocation();
    startLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    displayLocation();
}
}
```

I am totally confused on how to get this solved. App works well from Signing In and Register. But finding real time Location, APP crashed. Your solution will gladly go a long way to helping me.

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with this?